# Firebase Failed to Increment Counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, firebase

I have two firebase scripts; one of them is working fine but other not. I don't have any idea what is going on. Those two scripts are based on same logic. Only difference is that counter 2 data is always incremented irrespective of website home page or post page while counter 1 data is incremented only it is post page (i.e. pathname!='/'). Fortunately counter 1 is working fine but counter 2 not. I don't have any idea what i'm doing wrong..
Please help me to get rid of this bug. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

```js
  $(function(){
    var parentDataRef = 'https://blablabla.firebaseio.com/';
    
    //counter 1
      var postRef = new Firebase(parentDataRef+'one');
      getFirebaseData(postRef,'post',function(pData){
        alert(pData);
      });

    
    //counter 2
    var blogRef = new Firebase(parentDataRef+'two');
    getFirebaseData(blogRef,'blog',function(bData){
      alert(bData);
    });  
  });



  //get Firebase data
  function getFirebaseData(r,bp,back){ //Reference, Blog or Post, Return data
    var doctitle = document.title;
    r.once('value', function(e) {
      var data=e.val();
      if (data==null){data=1;}
      else if (getCookie(doctitle)!='yes'){
        if (bp=='post' && window.location.pathname!='/') {data++;}
        else if (bp=='blog') {data++;}
      }
      
      r.set(data);
      back(data);
      setCookie(doctitle,'yes',7);
    });
  }


  //set Cookie Data
  function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays){
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = 'expires=' + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname+'='+cvalue+'; '+expires+'; path=/';
  }

  //get Cookie Data
  function getCookie(cname){
    var name = cname + '=';
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
      var c = ca[i];
      while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
      if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
        return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
      }
    }
    return '';
  }
```

Comment: What is the result you're seeing? Also, for incrementing a counter, have you tried Firebase [transactions](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/transaction.html)? They're specifically intended for use cases like counters where two clients might write to the same path at the same time.

Comment: We can't tell from this code sample what's going wrong either. Rob's advice on transactions will likely help. If not, check out [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Problem appears when cookie function is used..if I remove the cookie function, those two scripts are working fine..is there anything wrong with cookie function??  Thanks for help..but is also does the same with transaction..counter 2 is increasing while counter 1 remain as it is (not increasing)..thaks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest to use transactions your counters ?

```
var upvotesRef = new Firebase('https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/android/saving-data/fireblog/posts/-JRHTHaIs-jNPLXOQivY/upvotes');
upvotesRef.transaction(function (current_value) {
  return (current_value || 0) + 1;
});
```

Comment: Problem appears when cookie function is used..if I remove the cookie function, those two scripts are working fine..is there anything wrong with cookie function??  Thanks for help..but is also does the same with transaction..counter 2 is increasing while counter 1 remain as it is (not increasing)..thaks in advance..